# Which process establishes the connection with the database server?

Tags: python, webserver, database-connection, data-access-layer, database-server

Let's suppose we have a single host where there is a Web Server and a Database Server.

An external application sends an http request to the web server to access to the database.

The data access logic is made for example by Python API.

The web server takes the request and the Python application calls the method to connect to the database, e.g. MySQLdb.connect(...).

Which process establishes the connection with the database server and communicates with it? Is it the web server process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as Python application lives inside of the web server process, this process will establish the connection with database server.